# Apache Spark: union operation is not performed

Tags: java, apache-spark

I Know spark does lazy evaluation.

But is this expected behaviour??
With the below program the output is 20.

But if the print statement

```
  System.out.println("/////////////////// After "+MainRDD.count());
```

is uncommented, the output will be 40

I'm not doing this as is in my Application, But just to demonstrate , I created this program..

```
 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("JavaSparkSQL");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

JavaRDD<Integer> MainRDD;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
JavaRDD<Integer> tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}

MainRDD = sc.parallelize(list);// MainRDD.union(tmp);
System.out.println("//////////////////////First "+MainRDD.count());

list.clear();
for (int i = 20; i < 25; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
        list.add(i*j);
    }
    tmp = sc.parallelize(list);

  //      System.out.println("/////////////////// Before "+MainRDD.count());
    MainRDD = MainRDD.union(tmp);
//        System.out.println("/////////////////// After "+MainRDD.count());
    list.clear();
}

System.out.println("/////////////////// last "+MainRDD.count());
}
```

Comment: @eliash Really? I am actually surprised it works at all :)

Comment: Well, actually... I have a very weird behavior! I think it's due to the mutability of the data structure...

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is a mutable data structure you use to populate RDDs. When you call `sc.parallelize(list)`it doesn't the capture the state of the `ArrayList`. Since you call `clear` when you output the loop when data is actually evaluated there is no data at all.

Truth be told I don't know why this behavior changes when you call `count` method. Since RDD is not cached my guess is it is matter of either Spark or JVM internals but I won't even try to guess what is really going on there. Maybe someone smarter will be able to what the precise reason for this behavior.

Just to illustrate what is going on:

```
val arr = Array(1, 2, 3)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)

(0 until 3).foreach(arr(_) = 99)
val tmp = sc.parallelize(arr)

tmp.union(rdd).collect
// Array[Int] = Array(99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99)
```

vs.

```
val arr = Array(1, 2, 3)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)
rdd.count()
// Long = 3

(0 until 3).foreach(arr(_) = 99)
val tmp = sc.parallelize(arr)

tmp.union(rdd).collect
// Array[Int] = Array(99, 99, 99, 1, 2, 3)

sc.getRDDStorageInfo
// Array[org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo] = Array()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be wise to open an issue for that?

Comment: From whatever little I know, as spark does lazy evaluation, unless I call the count method/some operation on RDD, it is not calculated/ modified.. Hence this situation.. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Anil Executing an action evaluates RDD but shouldn't persist results unless RDD is cached. As far as I am concerened you should actually get an empty RDD each time.  But I could be wrong. Mutable data structures are evil and should be forbidden :)

Comment: I know abit about mutable objects but didn't understand why there's a need for an RDD to be mutable

Comment: RDDs are not mutable. At least not when you think about data they represent.

Comment: @eliasah I thought about it and I tend to believe this is not a bug. I don't see any reasonable solution here.

Comment: @Anil I was actually suggesting to zero323 to open an issue and not you :)